# Softlinking /home to a new folder on a big volume

Tags: linux, symlink

I have a new large volume I would like to create a folder in called home to serve the users home folders, so the location would be /bigvolume/home.  Would creating a softlink (ln -s) from /home to /bigvolume/home cause any problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I have never had problems doing that, and I done that on many machines.

If for some reason you didn't want to use a symlink then you could just do a [bind mount](http://aplawrence.com/Linux/mount_bind.html).

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was something like bind mount, but I couldn't remember the name of it for the life of me.